# Fetching youtube playlist items in reverse order

Tags: android, youtube

I am using the YouTube Data API (v3) and the Google API client libraries for youtube to fetch contents of a playlist.

I would like to display the playlist items in reverse chronological order for which I want to list the items from last page and going backwards.

Currently , I am using the Java example at - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

and looping over all search page results returned for the playlistid using getNextpagerToken() but ideally I would like to get the last pager first and then loop over it using getPreviousPageToken() .

Does anyone has a suggestion ?